# What's the name for small area statistics in France?

Tags: data, statistics, census, france

US has Census blocks and block groups. Canada has dissemination blocks and dissemination areas. UK has output areas and super output areas. Is there an equivalent in France—statistical areas defined as having, at most, several thousand people?

Comment: I am not an expert by any means -- 
Have you checked out the National Institute of Statistics and Economic Studies (INSEE)?  http://www.insee.fr/fr/bases-de-donnees/default.asp?page=recensements.htm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

they have IRIS which a sub division of municipalities [INSEE](http://www.insee.fr/fr/methodes/default.asp?page=zonages/iris.htm)

Comment: Thanks, I think this is just what I'm looking for. Google translate tells me French urban areas -- "municipalities" -- are split into these IRIS "neighborhoods," each having a population of about 2,000 people. They are "built from geographical and statistical criteria and, if possible, each IRIS must be uniform from the perspective of the habitat. IRIS offer the most sophisticated tool to date to describe the internal structure of nearly 1,900 municipalities of at least 5,000" people. I'm not a French speaker. Is the translation OK?

Comment: Found a great definitions page in English: http://www.insee.fr/en/methodes/default.asp?page=definitions/iris.htm